# libpaypalmobile.a symbols not found in architecture error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6, ios6.1

Hi i integrated paypal Mobile sdk in my app. I got libpaypalmobile.a symbols not found in architecture i386 error. i added all required frameworks. when i build the project, i got that error. i attached screen shot also.

i googled so much, but i cant find required answer.

i used SDWebImage also, when i place -ObjC --lstdc++ in other linker flags, this error is coming.
please any one can tell the solution or suggestions.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are libXML, Security and libz libraries included?

Comment: @Prince Were you able to solve this problem? i am having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you checked whether the plugin is listed in `Target -> Build Phases -> Link with binary libraries` ?
2. Try enabling `Build Active Architecture Only` by setting its value `YES`

Comment: plugin is listed in build phases and i set build active architecture only value is yes.... but no use, same error

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have added all the required frameworks in project related to the API.

- Make sure you have added all header files & library & its linked properly

Than follow this:

- Go to Targets -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags
- Add -lc++ & -ObjC to it

This worked for me solve errors same as above.